# scanf() doesn't wait for string input in a loop

Tags: c, loops, scanf

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        printf("Enter the name of the player:\n");
        char* name;
        scanf(" %s", name);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Expected program to ask for the name 4 times and let user input 4 names

Input: Name

Output:

Enter the name of the player:

Name

Enter the name of the player:

Enter the name of the player:

Enter the name of the player:

---

Will be very grateful if you help me to fix it

Comment: The variable `name` is a pointer, but ***where does it point?*** You need an *array* here instead.

Comment: That program has undefined behavior. `name` holds some uninitialized address, anything could happen when you try to use it. Replace it with something like `char name[1024];`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
 int i;
 char name[100];
 for (i = 0; i < 4; i++)
 {
     printf("Enter the name of the player:\n");
     
     scanf(" %s", name);
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass into "scanf" a non-allocated pointer because "scanf" only fill the chars and not allocate the pointer.